# Block is not a blockNode . How to resolve problem which is related to npm semver?

Tags: reactjs, npm, draftjs, semantic-versioning, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am having trouble with peerDependencies. I have a react application , which imports *react-draft-whysiwyg*. 
My main application has current dependencies `

`"Dependencies": {
    ... // another packages
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "react": "16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "16.4.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": 
    "git+ssh://repo-url/shared/forks/react-draft-wysiwyg.git#0.0.4",
    ... // another packages
}`

*react-draft-whysiwyg* on histurn has current package.json structure`

`"devDependencies": {
    ... // another packages
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.3",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "react": "16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "16.4.0",
    ... // another packages
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "draft-js": "^0.10.x",
    "immutable": "3.x.x || 4.x.x",
    "react": "0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x || ^16.0.0-0 || 16.x.x",
    "react-dom": "0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x.x || ^16.0.0-0 || 16.x.x"
  },`

The actual problem is in development stage, as i need to run *react-draft-whysiwyg* separately to test it with main app. It throws an error (see below picture) `

[image]

I think it doesn't matter to provide detailed steps of how error is reproduced , as i consider it could be a problem related to *peerDependencies* , because in rpoduction it works very well.As i understand npm resolves that versioning problems automatically, but in development i need to install the right versions of mentioned packages.
I have already tried different options , but couldnt manage to solve it. Maybe i just cant solve the problem with peerDependencies and install correct versions of mentioned packages in development.